# Why are the properties of anonymous types in C# read-only?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

In C#, the properties of anonymous types are read-only:

```
var person = new { Surname = "Smith", OtherNames = "John" };
person.Surname = "Johnson";  // ERROR: .Surname is read-only
```

Of course I can declare a real class if I want writable fields or properties, but regardless, what is the reasoning behind this design decision to make the properties read-only?

Comment: Safety, maybe? If you didn't specify they were writable, don't let them be written? Besides, those are properties, not fields.

Comment: Good point, I'll change the text. I did also wonder why they couldn't be fields declared with "readonly"...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622664/what-is-immutability-and-why-should-i-worry-about-it

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Interesting article on that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sreekarc/archive/2007/04/03/immutable-the-new-anonymous-type.aspx).  From there ...

> ... [B]y ensuring that the members do
>   not change, we ensure that the hash is
>   constant for the lifetime of the
>   object.This allows anonymous types to
>   be used with collections like
>   hashtables, without actually losing
>   them when the members are modified.
>   There are a lot of benefits of
>   immutabilty in that, it drastically
>   simplifies the code that uses the
>   object since they can only be assigned
>   values when created and then just used
>   (think threading)

Comment: Yes there are a lot of benefits to immutability, but there are a lot of benefits to mutability as well - you could use the above argument to argue that Lists should be immutable as well.  This decision makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: It is interesting because anonymous types in vb.net are mutable...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately features like "top level statements" seem to be more important than the ability to pass complex data around and manipulate it as needed without having to create a class for that data.  Its a HUGE gap in C# who's omission makes little sense to me.  You basically have to use Dictionary<string,object> as this is the only way to do this.  But let me ask any C# designers who might encounter this page, which is cleaner and less verbose between these 2 code snippets?

```
        var data = new 
        {
            Username = "My Username",
            FullName = "John Smith",
            Age = 22,
            Salary = 11.5,               
            IsEmployee = true,
            DOB = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,              
        };
        data.FullName = "Hello worlder";

        var data2 = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["Username"] = "My Username",
            ["FullName"] = "John Smith",
            ["Age"] = 22,
            ["Salary"] = 11.5,
            ["IsEmployee"] = true,
            ["DOB"] = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        };
        data["FullName"] = "john smith";
```