# Why anonymous type are immutable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, anonymous-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are the properties of anonymous types in C# read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089406/why-are-the-properties-of-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp-read-only)

I wrote something like this,

```
 var suspense = new { Name = "Android", Market = string.Empty };
 suspense.Market = "Potential";
```

**.NET throws error**

> Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Market' cannot be assigned to --
>   it is read only

I know that AnonymousTypes in C# are immutable, but why? Is this due to some limitation with CLR?

Comment: I'd rather wonder about the opposite. Why is it so hard to create immutable named types?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sreekarc/archive/2007/04/03/immutable-the-new-anonymous-type.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/30/anonymous-types-unify-within-an-assembly-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motivating factor for driving the immutable anonymous types was **because the LINQ APIs used hash tables internally and returning projections of anonymous types that could be modified was a dangerous situation.**

You can check :

[Immutable types: understand their benefits and use them](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/)

[**Anonymous Types and Object Identities By Tim Ng on MSDN**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timng/archive/2007/05/28/anonymous-types-and-object-identities.aspx)

Comment: VB.NET is supporting mutable anonymous type by adding Key to respective field(s), then what is the limitation in c#?

Comment: @vinodpthmn - not sure on that you can check the article which also taking vb.net as base language read second artile on msdn