# How to iterate through a list and edit is content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var courses = _repository.GetAllCoursesDetailsByCourseId(id);
var result = (from s in courses select new {  id = s.Course_ID,  name=s.Course_Date}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now what i want to do is to iterate through result and edit all of its "name" content . . 
a rough idea is below :

```
foreach (var i in result)
{
     string[] temp = i.name.Split(',');
     string[] token = temp[0].Split(' ');
     string newtemp = token[1] + " " + temp[1];
     i.name = newtemp;
}
```

But this is not working. How can i edit the content in var result?

Comment: Could you elaborate about what is not working ? Do you get an error ? Results elements not changed after the foreach ?

Comment: You must add the modified data into another list.

Comment: it underlines i.name and says Readonly property cannot be used as assignment target

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zshzt6s3(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: just the list . so that i pass it back to the view

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zshzt6s3(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Then how you modify Readonly properties. Change it read/write.

Comment: have not declared it readonly anywhere

Answer (score 0):

```
Try something like this:

foreach (var i in result)
{
 string temp = i.name.Split(',');
 string token = temp.Split(' ');
 string newtemp = token + " " + temp;
 i.name = newtemp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous objects are immutable, that's why you're getting the Readonly error message.

I suggest you look here for some more information: [Why are the properties of anonymous types in C# read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089406/why-are-the-properties-of-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous type properties are [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Build a function that does the name generation and then use it directly in the LINQ:

```
private string GenerateNewName(string name) {
    string temp = name.Split(',');
    string token = temp.Split(' ');
    return token + " " + temp;
}

var result = (from s in courses select new {  id = s.Course_ID,  name=GenerateNewName(s.Course_Date)}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. (I didn't change your code, but you should be careful with your index, if you didn't found any ',' or ' ' you will throw an exception)

```
var result = (from s in courses select new {  id = s.Course_ID,  name= splitName(s.Course_Date) }).Distinct().ToList();

private string splitName(string value)
{
     string[] temp = i.name.Split(',');
     string[] token = temp[0].Split(' ');
     return (token[1] + " " + temp[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use foreach ,whatever changes you do, the changes are in the temp var i, not in the actual list, try using the traditonal for or an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As @Muhammad said, you need another list with updated values. You can extend your list search through *Where* extension method on any list, then apply your changes like below,

```
var newResult = result.Where(q=> q.name == "ValueToUpdate").ToList().ForEach(i => i.name = "NewValue");
```