# Logic Method From a LINQ to SQL expression

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best practice for the following scenario:

I have a LINQ to SQL expression where in its projection I want to call a private method.
I understand that my method cannot be translated into SQL, but I do need the logic.
Changing the property after getting the query result is not possible since you cannot change a projected property (it is read only).

10x

```
var projectedOrders = from order in orders
    select new
    {
        orderId = order.Id,
        orderName = order.FriendlyName,
        OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
        CustomerName = helper.GetUserNameByUserId(order.UserId)
    };
```

Comment: Changing the property on the existing item is not possible, but you could `select` out a new collection after getting the result.

Comment: If the method is simple, how about using dynamic LINQ? See end of [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/19/dynamic-linq-part-2-evolution.aspx) for example and explanation

Comment: @paqogomez check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089406/why-are-the-properties-of-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp-read-only

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I was suggesting what all these answers are suggesting, you have to do it twice.  Once to get the result, then create a new array that calculates your value.  Exactly as @Jaimec suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to do it in 2 steps

- query the raw data from the database, and materialize it
- project onwards using your logic

---

```
var projectedOrders = (from order in orders
                          select new
                          {
                              orderId = order.Id,
                              orderName = order.FriendlyName,
                              OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
                              UserId= order.UserId
                          })
                       .ToArray()
                       .Select(o =>
                           new{
                              o.orderId,
                              o.orderName,
                              o.OrderDate,
                              CustomerName = helper.GetUserNameByUserId(o.UserId)

                           });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `UserId` temporarily into a property and set `CustomerNames` to *null*, then use a loop after your query and change the value of CustomerNames:

```
var projectedOrders = (from order in orders
                      select new
                      {
                              orderId = order.Id,
                              orderName = order.FriendlyName,
                              OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
                              UserId = order.UserId,
                              CustomerName = null
                       }).ToList();

foreach(var order in projectedOrders)
        order.CustomerName = helper.GetUserNameByUserId(order.UserId);
```

Comment: This won't work since, as I mentioned, projections properties are read-only

Comment: I don't get that, what makes them read-only ? are you not using anonymous type in your real code?