# How to add a new value to an anonymous type

Tags: c#, json

is it possible to add a value to existing json object?

**My example code**:

```
var obj = new { Vall = "myVal1", Val2 = "myVal2", Val3 = "myVal3" };
```

*this is what I'm trying to do*:

```
obj.AddValue(Val4, "myVal4");
```

Comment: @TheRuler JSON would have `"Val1": "myVal1"`  - note that the key is quoted, and the separator is a colon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are the properties of anonymous types in C# read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089406/why-are-the-properties-of-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp-read-only)

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj = new { Vall = "myVal1", Val2 = "myVal2", Val3 = "myVal3" };
```

is not JSON, despite the similarity. That is a compiler-generated "anonymous type", which means the compiler creates a type for you with three `string` properties named `Val1`, `Val` and `Val3`. Other than the fact that you can't speak the name of the type (it is anonymous), it is a pretty normal .NET class. No, you can't add extra properties to a class at runtime.

The closest thing to what you want *might* be `ExpandoObject`, but to be honest it sounds like you're trying to do something peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

As everybody else pointed out, you are dealing with `anonymous types` here, not with JSON objects. Unfortunately, they are autogenerated types in compiled code and this mean they cannot be altered as you wish.

A simple workaround would be declaring a new anonymous type that can store an additional field and setting the values of the common fields to the ones of the old object as follows:

```
var obj_old = new { Vall = "myVal1", Val2 = "myVal2", Val3 = "myVal3" };
var obj_new = new { Vall = obj_old.Vall, Val2 = obj_old.Val2, Val3 = obj_old.Val3, Val4 = "myVal4" };
```

Alternatively, declare the object with an additional field whose value can be set when needed:

```
var obj = new { Vall = "myVal1", Val2 = "myVal2", Val3 = "myVal3", Val4 = String.Empty };
// ...
obj.Val4 = "myVal4";
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties of anonymous types in C# is read-only, you can clone this object and add your property using `Json.Net` like this:

```
    var obj = new { ID = 1234, Name = "FooBar" };
    obj = JObject.FromObject(obj).Add("feeClass", "A");
```

Final Json:

```
{
  "ID": 1234,
  "Name": "FooBar",
  "feeClass": "A"
}
```