# How To Test if a Type is Anonymous?

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-types

I have the following method which serialises an object to a HTML tag. I only want to do this though if the type isn't Anonymous.

```
private void MergeTypeDataToTag(object typeData)
{
    if (typeData != null)
    {
        Type elementType = typeData.GetType();

        if (/* elementType != AnonymousType */)
        {
            _tag.Attributes.Add("class", elementType.Name);    
        }

        // do some more stuff
    }
}
```

Can somebody show me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From [http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=191](https://web.archive.org/web/20130817025324/http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=191):

```
private static bool CheckIfAnonymousType(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

    // HACK: The only way to detect anonymous types right now.
    return Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
        && type.IsGenericType && type.Name.Contains("AnonymousType")
        && (type.Name.StartsWith("<>") || type.Name.StartsWith("VB$"))
        && type.Attributes.HasFlag(TypeAttributes.NotPublic);
}
```

EDIT:
Another link with extension method: [Determining whether a Type is an Anonymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650681/determining-whether-a-type-is-an-anonymous-type)

Comment: source from http://jclaes.blogspot.com/2011/05/checking-for-anonymous-types.html

Comment: Sadly this is false for `new{}.GetType()`

But i think `&& type.IsGenericType` can savely be removed.

Comment: Looks like you need `(type.Name.Contains("AnonymousType") || type.Name.Contains("AnonType"))` to be compatible with Mono. Source: [NancyFx extension method](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ViewEngines/Extensions.cs)

Comment: Now it's 2016, do someone know if is there some new possible implementation?

Comment: `(type.Attributes & TypeAttributes.NotPublic) == TypeAttributes.NotPublic` is trivially always true, because `TypeAttributes.NotPublic == 0`. This check should be done with `TypeAttributes.Public`.

Answer (score 22):

Quick and dirty:

```
if(obj.GetType().Name.Contains("AnonymousType"))
```

Comment: I'm very tempted to click +1. Must not click!! xD

Comment: Dirty and slow unfortunately.

Comment: I like this one because it's very simple and should only error in the pathological case where someone has created class with "AnonymousType" in the name, but the object is not actually an anonymous type.  That hypothetical someone should be hypothetically flogged.

Answer (score 16):

You can just check if the namespace is null.

```
public static bool IsAnonymousType(this object instance)
{

    if (instance==null)
        return false;

    return instance.GetType().Namespace == null;
}
```

Comment: does this work for mono?

Comment: There are cases where this does not hold true.  I'm not sure of all cases where this fails, but one example is where a lambda expression is used within a protected concrete method of an abstract class with generic parameters. I'm sure there are simpler cases that would also fail.

Comment: @DalSoft Place any class outside a namespace and there you go, which is actually common in some frameworks.

Comment: @DalSoft Woot^^ I wonder if this is the case in mono as well. Testing..

Comment: @DalSoft It's null in Mono 2.0

Comment: @DalSoft Ah, you made a woops. You tested if typeof(Type)'s namespace was null. Fixed: http://rextester.com/BOL44171 (true, true)

Comment: Woops sorry was having a bad day yesterday - good to know. So in terms of using this then I guess it's a couple of lines for most use cases, or pick a more verbose solution if you need to catch all cases.

Answer (score 8):

Well, today compiier generates anonymous types as generic AND sealed classes. A paradoxal combination since specialization of a generic class is a kind of inheritance, isn't?
So you can check for this:
1. Is this a generic type?
Yes => 2) is its definition sealed && not public?
Yes => 3) is its definition has CompilerGeneratedAttribute attribute? 
I guess, if these 3 criteria are true together, we have an anonymous type...
Well... There is a problem with ANY of methods described - they are use aspects that may change in next versions of .NET and it will be so until Microsoft will add IsAnonymous boolean property to Type class. Hope it will happen before we all die... 
Until that day, it can be checked like so:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Reflection;

public static class AnonymousTypesSupport
{
    public static bool IsAnonymous(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var d = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            if (d.IsClass && d.IsSealed && d.Attributes.HasFlag(TypeAttributes.NotPublic))
            {
                var attributes = d.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false);
                if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                {
                    //WOW! We have an anonymous type!!!
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool IsAnonymousType<T>(this T instance)
    {
        return IsAnonymous(instance.GetType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Check for `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` and `DebuggerDisplayAttribute.Type`

here is the code generated by the compiler for an anomymous type

```
[CompilerGenerated, DebuggerDisplay(@"\{ a = {a} }", Type="<Anonymous Type>")]
internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType0<<a>j__TPar>
{
...
}
```

Comment: Only works when compiling in debug mode.

Comment: Works in release mode too!.

            var anonType = new {a = 1, b = 2}.GetType();
            anonType.CustomAttributes.Select(e => e.AttributeType).Should().Contain(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute));