# In C#, how do you one-way serialize the unserializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

Oftentimes, I need to serialize an object, either for logging or debugging.  This is a one-way serialization -- I don't need to get it back out later, I just need to turn an object into a string to write it somewhere.

Yes, yes -- this is why you should always override the `ToString` method.  I know this.  But I'm often dealing with objects I didn't write and can't change.  Additionally, I don't want to have to write and update a ToString method for every class I write.

XML serialization offers a seemingly perfect solution -- just flatten that object out into XML.  But there are so many limitations, specifically that you can't serialize IDictionary, and you have to have a parameterless constructor.  I can get around these in my classes, but -- again -- I'm often working with other people's classes.

So, what's the solution to getting an comprehensive string representation of an object?  Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe some reflection to iterate and render the members into a string? However, that's slow and therefore only sensible for error scenarios where performance does not matter (anymore)...

Answer (score 38):

How about an extension method with your own logic (and maybe some Reflection)?

```
public static class SerializerExtension
{
    public static String OneWaySerialize(this Object obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        {
            return "NULL";
        }
        if (obj.GetType().IsPrimitive || obj.GetType() == typeof(String))
        {
            if (obj is String)
                return String.Format("\"{0}\"", obj);
            if (obj is Char)
                return String.Format("'{0}'", obj);
            return obj.ToString();
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        if (IsEnumerableType(objType))
        {
            builder.Append("[");

            IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)obj).GetEnumerator();
            Boolean moreElements = enumerator.MoveNext();
            while (moreElements)
            {
                builder.Append(enumerator.Current.OneWaySerialize());
                moreElements = enumerator.MoveNext();
                if (moreElements)
                {
                    builder.Append(",");
                }
            }

            builder.Append("]");
        }
        else
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0} {{ ", IsAnonymousType(objType) ? "new" : objType.Name);

            PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
            for (Int32 p = properties.Length; p > 0; p--)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = properties[p-1];
                String propName = prop.Name;
                Object propValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
                builder.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", propName, propValue.OneWaySerialize());
                if (p > 1)
                {
                    builder.Append(", ");
                }
            }

            builder.Append(" }");
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2483054/298053
    private static Boolean IsAnonymousType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
            && type.IsGenericType && type.Name.Contains("AnonymousType")
            && (type.Name.StartsWith("<>") || type.Name.StartsWith("VB$"))
            && (type.Attributes & TypeAttributes.NotPublic) == TypeAttributes.NotPublic;
    }

    private static Boolean IsEnumerableType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (intType.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null || (intType.IsGenericType && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call it like so:

```
someDefinedObject.OneWaySerialize();
```

**Revisisons**

1. Initial version
2. Updated 12.26.2012

   - Added check for IEnumerable (thanks aboveyou00)
   - Added check for anonymous type (and just label it "new" when output)

Comment: +1: Extension method and reflection would be my favorites here, making sure to serialize only publicly available properties. Might be a little boggy for large classes though.

Comment: Obviously not for the performance sensitive, but it seems more like a debugging tool than a production one so reflection should be _satisfactory_.

Comment: Absolutely, just putting it out there in case OP decided to put it into a logging mechanism for large objects in a heavy use environment. Given OP doesn't want to write one for "every object" I'd guess he's planning to use this "a lot".

Comment: How would you handle recursion?  If a property is a List<string>, for instance, how do I list all the values of that?  I know I can check for IEnumerable, but I'm just wondering how far you take.  How far do you recurse down the rabbithole?

Comment: @Deane: updated, take that for a spin. tried it on some basic objects, but I'm sure it's not 100% bullet-proof (after all, i wrote it ;p)

Comment: I'm getting a Stack Overflow exception, which tells me it's recursing uncontrollably somewhere.  I'm trying to debug...

Comment: Tried to do it in LinqPad and it crashed it.  I think calling OneWaySerialize all the way down the stack is biting off more than the runtime wants to chew... :-)

Comment: @Deane: let me know. All i tested it on was primitive types, a basic object with primitive types, an object with primitive and enumerable of primitive and a more complex object with an enumerable of other objects (which have primitive types). All worked, but didn't go deep in to testing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21399/discussion-between-deane-and-brad-christie)

Comment: Just so you know: IsEnumerableType only checks for generic enumerations (IEnumerable<>). It doesn't check for IEnumerable. Not a big deal, but for the sake of completeness...

Comment: @aboveyou00: Indeed, you are correct. I didn't get _too_ exhaustive on the list of possibilities, but the basic premise is there. I'll add a short-circuit in there though. ;-)

Answer (score 14):

If you're comfortable serializing to JSON, [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a great solution to this problem.